# How can I get apply 'semantic-ui' to my node.js project? node.js view is made up of pug file

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-ui

I want to use `fomantic-ui = semantic-ui`. I followed the "Install" page, but it isn't working:

```
$ npm init
$ npm install --save fomantic-ui

"dependencies": {
  ...
  "fomantic-ui": "^2.7.5"
  ...
}

$ npx gulp build
```

and

```
<!-- You MUST include jQuery before Fomantic -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/semantic/dist/semantic.min.css">
<script src="/semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

I changed this code to `pug(jade)` code. The `semantic` folder is the parent of this pug file, so I added '..' to the CSS directory.

Comment: Added code layout, which also made the HTML visible and tidied up the typing.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks to your help, I will try to change the layout next time. I want to show like you done but, I didn't know how can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

https://fomantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html

I saw this web page. and I change the html code to pug code